# What is a bathtub with two levels called?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for a bathtub that has two levels — meaning it has a rectangular hole(?)/step for feet/legs (kind of like bathtub with a foot basin?) that allows you to basically sit in the shower like in a chair?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the term

***Walk-in bath(tub)***:

> A walk-in bath is essentially a bath with a door on the side, meaning that you do not need to step over the side to enter the bath. Most tend to be double-height where you sit rather than lie down, to ensure that your whole body is submerged in the water and keep you warm.

[image]

(EZ bath)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Most walk-in baths have a chair-height seat; Maybe it would be better if you could include a picture of the interior of the bathtub ([something like this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQldGAa2JKEFT1F5dJRLKT80fy7hk8CzFzbmurIIwQPEQ&s)).

Comment: Not all split-level tubs have doors, is probably why it was downvoted.

Comment: Although it's not clear if the OP was asking about this type of bath or not, so it could be a correct answer.

Comment: Not all walk in tubs have seats. They usually do, since they are marketed as accessibility solutions and having a seat solves some other accessibility problems. [Homeability](http://homeability.com/accessible-bathtub-styles-overview/) lists many different types of accessible bathtubs, including a retrofitted tub, which is a regular tub (no seat) with part of the side cut out and possibly replaced with a door.

Comment: As Laurel said, 'not all walk in tubs have seats', but it is also true that not all tubs designed for sitting are of the walk-in kind; the two are independent characteristics of tubs, although they often go together.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the people who sell them, call them "a showertub" or "a shower tub":

[image: Armitage Shanks Showertub]

(From [Aqva Bathrooms](https://www.aqva.co.uk/Bathrooms/104833).)

Answer (score 1):

The term is ***sitz bath***. It is an obvious adaptation of the German term *Sitzbad*, but dictionaries do treat it as an English term. It is rarely heard, because what it stands for is rarely seen in the bathrooms of the English-speaking word, except as a walk-in bath. When something is, at the same time, a sitz bath and a walk-in bath, its latter aspect is more significant, so it is natural that it is referred to as a walk-in bath rather than a sitz bath.